# Jquery autocomplete refer to texbox which was used

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using jquery autocomplete from this webpage http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

the usage is pretty simple

```
var options = { 
       serviceUrl:'Autocomplete', 
       minChars:3,
       deferRequestBy:200, 
       onSelect: function(value, data){ 
           alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); 
       }
 };

$('#someTextBox').autocomplete(options);
```

my question is if I can somehow know that onSelect was applied on someTextBox cos if I want to use this on more then one textBox it could be nice to have just one `onSelect` function.

Comment: Try `this`, `onSelect: function(value, data){ alert(this.id); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just changed in jquery autocomplate code return function to this

```
onSelect: function (i) {
    var me, fn, s, d;
    me = this;
    fn = me.options.onSelect;
    s = me.suggestions[i];
    d = me.data[i];
    me.el.val(me.getValue(s));
    if ($.isFunction(fn)) { fn(s, d, me.el[0].id); }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same textbox id to all the textbox which u need to apply the effect. So by calling the textbox id in js it will automatically applied to all the textboxex which has the same id

Comment: no i can't, how would i know then which textboxt was change and which fileld i should change in the db?